Migrating from SQLite to MySQL Django (not working)
I'm trying to implement the MySQL instead of the SQLite, and the instructions are pretty straight forward, but, when I run the server again it stops after the system check identified no issues (0 silenced)., which indicates that it can't establish a connection to the database. but everything checks out.
I did this step in the database migration:

Installing Mysql server && mysqlclient
Create a database and a user and grant all permissions to that database
add to the setting.py file the database & user settings:

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'auth',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1', """localhost not working (Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2))"""
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

Am I missing anything out? Why isn't it working?

What error do you get?

no error, just freezes after the system check, and the migrate and makemigrations freezes too, doesn't give a anwser
